vb.net - How can 'the Parameter is incorrect' be true when path opens the file?
I am looping through PDF files in a directory on a server using the "following code, which works in another app, but just changing the path here results in a System.IO.IOException: 'The parameter is incorrect Error' here.
Dim path As String = "c:\serv\File.txt"
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()


For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles("xxxx.local\yyyyyyyy$\Accounts\11e. xxxx Management Accounts\xxxxxxx xxxxxxx\Sales Analysis\xxxxx Weekly Invoicing\xxxx\WK xx\WK xx xxxx Full Invoices.pdf")

    Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(file)
    For page As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
        Dim currentText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy)
        Dim theLines As String() = currentText.Split(vbLf)

        For Each theLine In theLines
            sb.AppendLine(theLine)
        Next
    Next
 Next
       File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString())

The path appears to be correct and when I copy the path the error gives me into the run box, it opens up the required pdf?? Any ideas please?

Please use your eyes to look at the preview of your question and don't submit if the formatting is a mess. If you can't do simple things like that to help us help you, the chances of our helping you are reduced, so you lose out.

You are calling Directory.GetFiles but providing a path that appears to be for a file rather than a folder. I doubt you have a folder named "WK xx xxxx Full Invoices.pdf". This:
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles("xxxx.local\yyyyyyyy$\Accounts\11e. xxxx Management Accounts\xxxxxxx xxxxxxx\Sales Analysis\xxxxx Weekly Invoicing\xxxx\WK xx\WK xx xxxx Full Invoices.pdf")

should probably be more like this:
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles("xxxx.local\yyyyyyyy$\Accounts\11e. xxxx Management Accounts\xxxxxxx xxxxxxx\Sales Analysis\xxxxx Weekly Invoicing\xxxx\WK xx")

By the way, I had to add a double quote to that to make it valid code. How can you be posting code that doesn't compile when you should be simply copying it from the VS code window?
